# Missing right parenthesis issue in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select 
    aplikasi0_.ID_APLIKASI as ID_APLIKASI1_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.created_by as created_by2_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.created_dt as created_dt3_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.end_dt as end_dt4_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.modified_by as modified_by5_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.modified_dt as modified_dt6_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.status as status7_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_AGENT as ID_AGENT8_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_BANK_OPERATION as ID_BANK_OPERATION9_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_CABANG as ID_CABANG10_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_CENTRO as ID_CENTRO11_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_HUBUNGAN_DENGAN_PEMOHON as ID_HUBUNGAN_DENGA12_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_INDUSTRI as ID_INDUSTRI13_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_JABATAN as ID_JABATAN14_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_JENIS_KENDARAAN as ID_JENIS_KENDARAA15_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_JENIS_PEMBIAYAAN as ID_JENIS_PEMBIAYA16_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_JENIS_PRODUK as ID_JENIS_PRODUK17_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_KARYAWAN as ID_KARYAWAN18_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_KATEGORI_PRODUK as ID_KATEGORI_PRODU19_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_MEDIA as ID_MEDIA20_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_MERK_BARANG as ID_MERK_BARANG21_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_MODEL_BARANG as ID_MODEL_BARANG22_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_OUTLET_DEALER as ID_OUTLET_DEALER23_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_PORTOFOLIO as ID_PORTOFOLIO24_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_PROGRAM_MARKETING as ID_PROGRAM_MARKET25_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_SUB_PRODUK as ID_SUB_PRODUK26_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_SUMBER_APLIKASI as ID_SUMBER_APLIKAS27_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_SURVEYOR as ID_SURVEYOR28_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_TIPE_APLIKASI as ID_TIPE_APLIKASI29_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_TIPE_BARANG as ID_TIPE_BARANG30_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_TIPE_FINANCIAL as ID_TIPE_FINANCIAL31_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_TIPE_KONSUMEN as ID_TIPE_KONSUMEN32_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_TIPE_TOKO as ID_TIPE_TOKO33_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_WARNA as ID_WARNA34_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.KETERANGAN as KETERANGAN35_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_KONSUMEN as ID_KONSUMEN58_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_LEADS as ID_LEADS59_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.LIST_STOK as LIST_STOK36_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.MEDIATOR as MEDIATOR37_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.NAMA_TOKO as NAMA_TOKO38_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.NO_BOOKING_LAMA as NO_BOOKING_LAMA39_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.NO_BPKB as NO_BPKB40_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.NO_INVOICE as NO_INVOICE41_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.NO_MESIN as NO_MESIN42_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.NO_MOU as NO_MOU43_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.NO_RANGKA as NO_RANGKA44_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.ID_PEMBIAYAAN as ID_PEMBIAYAAN60_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.STATUS_APLIKASI as STATUS_APLIKASI45_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.STATUS_BPJS as STATUS_BPJS46_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.STATUS_DUKCAPIL as STATUS_DUKCAPIL47_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.STATUS_MINAT as STATUS_MINAT48_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.STATUS_SLIK as STATUS_SLIK49_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.STNK_ATAS_NAMA as STNK_ATAS_NAMA50_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.TAHUN as TAHUN51_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.TGL_APLIKASI as TGL_APLIKASI52_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.TGL_BAST as TGL_BAST53_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.TGL_JANJI_SURVEY as TGL_JANJI_SURVEY54_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.TGL_JT_INVOICE as TGL_JT_INVOICE55_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.TGL_JT_MOU as TGL_JT_MOU56_0_, 
    aplikasi0_.TOTAL_BARANG as TOTAL_BARANG57_0_, 
    (SELECT aplikasi0_.h.ID_APLIKASI 
     FROM MMF_TRX_HISTORI_APPROVAL h 
     WHERE h.ID_APLIKASI = aplikasi0_.ID_APLIKASI AND ROWNUM = 1  
     ORDER BY h.TGL_APPROVAL DESC 
     LIMIT 1) as formula1_ 
from 
    MMF_LOS.MMF_TRX_APLIKASI aplikasi0_ 
where 
    aplikasi0_.ID_TIPE_APLIKASI = 'REJ';
```

Comment: Is it mySQL or Oracle (as tagged)? Oracle does not support `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: i have remove LIMIT but still error

Comment: The error means some kind of syntax error that prevents Oracle from parsing your query and not necessarily missing parenthesis per se. Replace the 1st line with `SELECT *` and see if you still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `LIMIT` which is not the valid keyword in oracle.

Replace `LIMIT 1` with `fetch first row only`. (Oracle 12c or higher)

Cheers!!

Comment: I have never mentioned about `ROWNUM=1` in my answer. that is not an issue also. the issue is `LIMIT` keyword. Why should I highlight something in the answer which is not even related to the solution?